# VS 2010 switch between single/dual monitor easily

Tags: visual-studio-2010, multiple-monitors

I have spent the last few months gradually tweaking my multi-monitor layout and shortcuts etc. for VS 2010.  I'm really happy with it now.  I use dropbox to share the .settings file between my office and home machines.  It all works really nicely until I go mobile with my laptop and have only a single screen.  Then all my layout gets changed to an inferior single screen layout.

For now I make a copy of the .settings file before going to single screen.  Is there a better way.  Can I easily export just the layout settings for single and dual screen and choose which to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [import/export settings feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/1x6229t8%28v=vs.110%29).  [More info.](https://web.archive.org/web/20151011174952/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zainnab/archive/2010/09/18/export-your-window-layouts-vstipenv0040.aspx)